# Getting an Attribute error while trying to alter a related model on a django detailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a CarRent model that is a ForeignKey to the Car model, on a CarRent detailView after payment i want to alter the CarRent model as well as the Car model, the code works well for the CarRent model, but altering the Car model results in “AttributeError at /car/requests/4/
type object 'Car' has no attribute 'object'” error

```
class Car(models.Model):
    
    car_owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='car_owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    rented = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class CarRent(models.Model):

    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='rented_car', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='driver_renting', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active_rent = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    rent_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)



@login_required
@driver_required(redirect_field_name='app:home')
@csrf_protect
def car_rent_detail_view(request, pk):
    object = get_object_or_404(CarRent, id=pk)

    # queryset = Car.objects.get(id=pk)
    car_object = get_object_or_404(queryset, id=pk)

    paystack = PaystackAccount(
        settings.PAYSTACK_EMAIL,
        settings.PAYSTACK_PUBLIC_KEY,
        object.total_cost
    )


    context = {'object': object, 'pk_public': settings.PAYSTACK_PUBLIC_KEY, 'currency': 'NGN', 'paystack': paystack,
               }


    if request.method == 'POST':
        if paystack.verify_transaction(request.POST['reference']):
            messages.success(request, "paystack payment successfull")
            car_rented = Car.object.get(pk=pk)
            car_rented.rented = True

            rent_activation = CarRent.objects.get(pk=pk)
            rent_activation.active_rent = True
            rent_activation.rent_paid = True
            rent_activation.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your Rent has successfully being updated")

    return render(request, 'app/CarRent_detail.html', context=context)
```

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a typo, you need to use `objects` to access manager method, not object. So replace:

```
car_rented = Car.object.get(pk=pk)
                 ^^^^^^
```

With:

```
car_rented = Car.objects.get(rented_car__pk=pk)
```

You can reverse query from Car model to CarRent via `related_name`(which is 'rented_car'). More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the code ran w/o any error, but i didn't get the desired result, as a different Car model was affected, problem seems to be that the pk value for `CarRent` is diferent from that of a related `Car` i need a way to use queryset to select the car that's related to a particular CarRent.